# WebView display wrong content after adding to FrameLayout

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to use this code (from [here](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/)):

```
public class StatePreservingImplActivity extends Activity {
  protected FrameLayout webViewPlaceholder;
  protected WebView webView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.state_preserving_impl);

    // Initialize the UI
    initUI();
  }

  protected void initUI() {
    // Retrieve UI elements
    webViewPlaceholder = ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder));

    // Initialize the WebView if necessary
    if (webView == null) {
      // Create the webview
      webView = new WebView(this);
      webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
      webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
      webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
      webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

      // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

      // Load a page

    }
    //ATTENTION
    webView.loadUrl("http://MYPAGE.php");
    // Attach the WebView to its placeholder
    webViewPlaceholder.addView(webView);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (webView != null) {
      // Remove the WebView from the old placeholder
      webViewPlaceholder.removeView(webView);
    }

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Load the layout resource for the new configuration
    setContentView(R.layout.state_preserving_impl);

    // Reinitialize the UI
    initUI();
  }
```

In web view i'm trying to display page, which compute content size using JavaScript and window.innerWidth/height. After starting application everything is OK. But if i rotate display (on emulator via NumPad 7 or 9), webView display content for old values of window.innerWidth/height despite webView is reloaded URL (see //ATTENTION). If i rotate device 2 or 3 or 4 or more times it always use values that corresponded to a state before.

Investigation was so long but i suspect that in this line

```
webViewPlaceholder = ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder));
```

i get old instance of FrameLayout because new layout did not have time to finish loading.
And i still don't understand how in this code example WebView pass correct values of width and height to JavaScript before it linked to FrameLayout after application started.

I was trying to find solution but no success. I will be happy for any help.

P.S. sorry for my english skills.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. First of all i find onContentChanged() event and move initUI(); from OnConfigurationChanged(..) to it. Then disable cache and it works fine. Here is code that i changed:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (mapWebView != null) {
    // Remove the WebView from the old placeholder
        webViewPlaceholder.removeView(mapWebView);
        webView.clearView();
    }

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Load the layout resource for the new configuration
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view_layout1);
}


@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    initUI();
}
```